# How to terminate running batch script from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have the for loop batch script, sample like below.

test.bat

```
:loop
echo hello
goto loop
```

i want to terminate the above batch script through windows command line. i have tried below command but it's terminating all cmd.exe terminals. Could please help on this.

```
taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe
```

Comment: How are you running that script? from, an open `cmd.exe` window?, a shortcut,  program, script? What about terminating it? from another cmd.exe window, a batch file etc.? Unless you can provide us with sufficient information for us to reproduce your situation and environment, we are left only with guesses or potentially inefficient or inappropriate solutions. It would also be prudent to explain what command you're really using instead of `echo hello`, because that may affect the potential solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

Give the window a title:

**test.bat**

```
:loop
title TESTBATCH
echo hello
goto loop
```

Then kill by windowtitle.

```
taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq TESTBATCH"
```